# Como não publicar um arquivo de configuração asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou separando meu `web.config` em vários arquivos, por exemplo, existe agora o `connections.config` que meu `web.config` referencia da seguinte forma   `<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>`

Vou subir para o controle de versão esse arquivos connections.config com os dados de desenvolvimento, mas no servidor de produção vai existir um dele com os dados de conexão de produção.

Como eu faço para não publicar o arquivos que está no projeto, com os dados de desenvolvimento, por cima do que está no servidor.

Eu faço a publicação do sistema clicando com o botão direito no projeto, publisher. onde eu configurei um profile de `FTP`.

O que eu preciso fazer para ela nunca publicar o arquivo `connections.config`?

**Atualizando:**

Estou usando VS2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Usando arquivos de transformação](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301874).

Repare que seu arquivo `Web.config` deriva para outros dois:

- `Web.Release.config`;
- `Web.Debug.config`.

Quando você for publicar em produção, altere o `Release`.

Suponho que seu `Web.config` deva ser mais ou menos assim:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
  ...
</configuration>
```

No `Web.Release.config`, você usará assim:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  ...
  <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Remove" />
  ...
</configuration>
```

Faça um `Publish` apontando como configuração `Release` e veja o que acontece com o `Web.config` no diretório de publicação.

---

**EDIT**

Pelo seu comentário, acho que você quer também que o arquivo nem apareça na publicação.

- No *Solution Explorer*, botão direito no arquivo;
- Selecione a opção Properties;
- Na linha **Build Action**, selecione **None**.

Comment: Na vdd ele publicou o arquivo `connections.config` e removeu o `<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>` do `web.config`, o que eu queria é que ele publicasse o `web.config`, mas não publicasse o `connections.config`. Ou eu vi errado?

Comment: @user3517631 Editei a resposta.