# ConnectionString diferente para builds diferentes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tenho duas connection string, uma quando estou em desenvolvimento que usa meu banco local e outra para quando faço deploy da aplicação no Azure.

Quero que a aplicação saiba qual das duas usar dependendo do tipo de build que eu fizer. Qual a maneira mais simples de fazer isso?

Da para fazer a nível de connection string ou eu precisaria de dois Web.config diferentes?

Comment: Veja se isto te ajuda: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[O procedimento é muito parecido com esta resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77079/como-n%C3%A3o-publicar-um-arquivo-de-configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-asp-net-mvc/77086#77086), só que pra `<connectionstrings>`. Por exemplo:

## `Web.Release.config`

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection"
        connectionString="MinhaConnectionStringDeProdução"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

## `Web.Debug.config`

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DefaultConnection"
        connectionString="MinhaConnectionStringDeDebug"
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```