# Duas base de dados comunicarem com o mesmo modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Queria ter uma base de dados para produção e outra para desenvolvimento separar os dados reais dos dados de ambiente testes.
O problema é que não faço a minima ideia como fazer isso.
Criei um clone da minha base de dados de desenvolvimento com o "Schema Compare" do visual studio. 
Em modo "debug" iria correr a base de dados devenvolvimento e "release" correr a base de dados produção.
Preciso de ideias!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [ConnectionString diferente para builds diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80698/connectionstring-diferente-para-builds-diferentes)

Comment: Olá Simão, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa a resposta na pergunta [ConnectionString diferente para builds diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80698/connectionstring-diferente-para-builds-diferentes) você poderá utilizar as [**Diretivas de pré-processamento**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80698/connectionstring-diferente-para-builds-diferentes).

"*As diretivas #if, #elif, #else e #endif são usadas no pré-processamento condicional, por exemplo, para verificar se um símbolo ou símbolos são verdadeiros.*" ou seja, a linha só é compilada conforme o modo configurado - Release ou Debug.

Para criar uma string de conexão condicionada a bancos diferentes (Produção e Homologação), use o `#if (DEBUG)`, siga os passos:

Agora no seu código, você fará o seguinte:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class _Default : Page {
    private string connectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

#if (DEBUG) //Ao compilar em modo DEBUG, a variável receberá o valor abaixo
        connectionString = "Data Source=seu_servidor;" +
                            "Initial Catalog=seu_banco_de_HOMOLOGACAO;" +
                            "User ID=seu_usuario; " +
                            "Password=sua_senha";
#else
        connectionString = "Data Source=seu_servidor;" +
                            "Initial Catalog=seu_banco_de_PRODUCAO;" +
                            "User ID=seu_usuario; " +
                            "Password=sua_senha";
#endif
    }

    internal void ConexaoBanco() {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM DBO.TABELA";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
                DataTable tabelaTeste = new DataTable("tabelaTeste");

                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                conn.Open();
                dataAdapter.Fill(tabelaTeste);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Obs: Da mesma forma isso poderá ser feito em Windows Forms.*

[#if (Referência de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)