# Como armazenar senhas em variáveis de ambiente (e remover elas do controle de versão)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, git, web.config, variáveis-de-ambiente

Estou migrando de um tfs local para um git privado (provavelmente bitbucket). 
Hoje eu simplesmente criptografo o webconfig, agora vou ter que tirar meus dados sensíveis do controle de versão (connection string, senhas, etc).

Como vocês fazem? Variáveis de ambiente?

Como provavelmente a resposta é sim, toda a vez que precisar adicionar ou editar uma key, eu vou até o infra-man e ele adiciona "na mão"?

E quanto a organização dessas variáveis? Uma variável para cada key? A nivel de usuário? Devo criptografar de alguma forma?

No caso eu uso jenkins, o deploy é automatizado. Mas estou estudando melhorias no processo. Acredito que as permissões do jenkins nao permitem alterar variáveis de ambiente, por isso a questão do cara da infra.

Eu estou intrigado também em como o azure criar as variaveis/configurações, Como o azure faz para mudar as veriáveis de ambiente pelo site/app? Conseguiria (deveria) simular isso nos meus sistemas também?

Answer (score 2):

> Como vocês fazem? Variáveis de ambiente?

Se você já criptografa seu `web.config`, não é preciso se preocupar com a segurança das informações, certo?

Basicamente, apenas a criptografia já resolve a questão da segurança, mas isto [supondo que você está usando este método](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx).

> Como provavelmente a resposta é sim, toda a vez que precisar adicionar ou editar uma key, eu vou até o infra-man e ele adiciona "na mão"?

Não é uma boa prática deixar isso com a infra. É melhor deixar a configuração de variáveis dentro do seu sistema, utilizando alguma forma interna de criptografia se for este o caso.

> E quanto a organização dessas variáveis? Uma variável para cada key? A nivel de usuário? Devo criptografar de alguma forma?

- Uma variável para cada chave;
- A nível de usuário é melhor colocar em banco de dados, e não em sistema;
- Se possível, criptografe.

> Como o azure faz para mudar as veriáveis de ambiente pelo site/app?

Normalmente não é o Azure que faz essa modificação, e sim um processo chamado [Transformação de `Web.config`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note que seu Visual Studio gera, além do `Web.config`, `Web.Release.config` e `Web.Debug.config`. Estes dois últimos arquivos são os responsáveis por ter a configuração que transforma seu `Web.config` em um arquivo modificado quando publicado.

> Conseguiria (deveria) simular isso nos meus sistemas também?

Isto é simples de simular. Veja as seguintes respostas em que explico isso:

- [ConnectionString diferente para builds diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80698/connectionstring-diferente-para-builds-diferentes/80700#80700)
- [Como não publicar um arquivo de configuração asp.net mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77079/como-n%C3%A3o-publicar-um-arquivo-de-configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-asp-net-mvc/77086#77086)
- [Como configurar o Web.config em projeto Cordova?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67671/como-configurar-o-web-config-em-projeto-cordova/67754#67754)

Comment: obrigado por responder. Como eu disse, hoje eu já criptografo o meu webconfig, mas eu quero usar um git (bitbucket) como controle de versão, ficando inviável utilizar essa técnica mais (pois como o risco de enviar senhas e connectionstrings para o bitbucket "sem querer"). Se vc olhar o azure, heroku, openshitf, etc, eles sempre usam variaveis de ambiente, pois "fora do mundo dotnet", manter esses dados no webconfig (mesmo criptografado) não é seguro.

Comment: Aqui tem uma referência: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestPracticesForPrivateConfigDataAndConnectionStringsInConfigurationInASPNETAndAzure.aspx